# Firestore: How can I correctly order by string with accent characters?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database include words with accent characters, such as the acute (é), tilde (ñ), umlaut (ü), and cedilla (ç).

I've created a custom index to order by this field, but the words with such characters are not correctly positioned.

**Example of expected order:**

["Água", "Amigo", "Barro", "Casa"]

**What I'm getting from Firestore:**

["Amigo", "Barro", "Casa", *"Água"*]

My query is as such:

```
let query = historyRef.whereField("createdByUserID", isEqualTo: state.loggedUser.uid).order(by: "itemName", descending: false)
```

Any pointers on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order your array collection like this:

```
var array = ["Amigo", "Barro", "Casa", "Água"]

array = array.sorted(by: {
    $0.lowercased().folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
        <
    $1.lowercased().folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Haroldo! It worked. 

I used the following adapted code and it worked perfectly: 

`array = array.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
        item1.lowercased().folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
          <
        item2.lowercased().folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
      })`

It would be nice though if Firestore could handle this directly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Firebase has no built-in option to sort ignoring diacritical marks. What you can do is add a `foldedName` property to your objects, and then have Firebase sort on that. To get this folded name, use

```
itemName.folding(options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive], locale: Locale.current)
```

Comment: Thanks, Gereon. Used your answer with Haroldo's below.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue sorting strings with diacritic marks (i.e., "Pâté"). I was using NSSortDescriptor to sort items fetched from Core Data, but it turns out that NSSortDescriptor can't sort this kind of strings well.

So I fetched the array of items without a NSSortDescriptor, then I manually sorted them with:

```
func sortArray() {
   array.sort(by: { item1, item2 in
                      
      return item1.itemName?.localizedStandardCompare((item2.itemName)!) == .orderedAscending } )
}
```